# Does cooking food prevent the body from efficiently absorbing minerals?

Tags: nutrition, cooking, minerals

It is true that we absorb minerals from cooked food less efficiently, because the membranes of our cells are made up mostly of [hydrogen ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_ion), therefore cooking food lose its anionic charge and it become more cationic? So in other words, it makes the food less healthy?

This can be demonstrated by Kirlian photography of cooked food which capture the phenomenon of electrical coronal discharges:

[image: Kirlian photography, cooked food]

<sup>Image found at: [The Tao of Dana](http://thetaoofdana.com/post/74865712793/the-energy-of-your-food-dramatically-affects-your)</sup>

Which gives the impression of reduction of anionic charge. Therefore if alkalinity is altered due to cooking, it could influence the structural, functional and enzymatic aspects of the food making the nutritions less absorbable.

Comment: The question is based on a flawed understanding. Chemiosmosis refers to the *movement* of hydrogen ions *through* a cellular membrane, not that the membrane is made up of hydrogen ions. Additionally, kirlian photography is unrelated to the health of a food.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cell membranes are made out of [phospholipids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phospholipid) and a lot of proteins, not of hydrogen ions. A membrane of hydrogen ions doesn't make any sense chemically in any way.

Cooking doesn't change the overall charge of molecules in food, you can't create or destroy charges out of thin air. To change the charges, essentially the pH of your solution, you need to either add acid or base. Of course you do that quite often in cooking, but the cooking process itself can't change any charges by itself. And even if it did, stomach acid has a very low pH and will change the charges of food anyway.

The Kirlian photography is pretty, but that's it. The strength of the effect is [sensitive to moisture](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/194/4262/263) for example, there are all kinds of reasons why cooked and raw food could look differently in these images.

Comment: 'Cooking doesn't change the overall charge of molecules in food', do you have reference for that? As far as I've read the microwave energy (not sure about conventional cooking) cause polar molecules and ions to rotate and collide inside the food which cause alternating electromagnetic field. See this [link](http://www.cfs.gov.hk/english/programme/programme_rafs/files/microwave_ra_e.pdf).

Comment: @kenorb http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation

Comment: See: [Microwave cooking](http://www.cfs.gov.hk/english/programme/programme_rafs/files/microwave_ra_e.pdf) 'polar molecules and ions inside the food will rotate or collide according to the alternating electromagnetic field' and 'the alternating electromagnetic field generated inside the microwave oven would lead to excitation, rotation/collision of polar molecules and ions inside the food'. Which cause changes in the ion orientation and movement.

Comment: @kenorb that still doesn't move charges out of the food. It's pretty much a fancy way of saying that microwaves heat up stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. More references would be welcomed. I'll have to look more deeper into it.